# present simple or progressive in this case

Tags: present-tense

In fact, every day I **check** the Royal Mail and read the latest info on the cyber incident because I am waiting for other parcels coming from the UK. Yes submit a claim

Could I use present progressive instead of present simple as the "checking" is something that I do everyday(it is repeated). The problem for me is that using present progressive feels like the checking is not finished but everyday my checking is completed.However I am  doing and will be doing  it until my parcel arrives,it is a temporary action.

Comment: The 'royal mail' might be the letters, parcels, etc, that the monarch sends and receives; the organisation in the UK that sells stamps and delivers mail is 'the Royal Mail' (a proper noun, the name of the organisation, to be exact Royal Mail Group Ltd).

Answer (score 3):

No, the progressive means that it is something that you *are doing now*, at least as an ongoing work in progress. If you are talking about a habit, you use the simple present. For example, I play poker every Tuesday.

Now, I have heard a number of Indian English speakers who will say *I am playing poker every Tuesday*. That sounds strange to Americans.

By the way, things that you do *every day* are *everyday* things. The compound word is the adjective. So:

> In fact, *every day* I check the Royal Mail.

It's preferable to put a comma after the word *fact*. Also, *Royal Mail* is a proper noun, so it is capitalized.

Comment: ok but when you say I am reading a book it does not mean you are reading it now

Comment: and even if the habit won't last long

Comment: @user5577 It does to me. Context can give a specific time in the future: I am going out to dinner tonight. But without such, it means now. Also, you wouldn't ever say "every day I am checking the Royal Mail," unless you were Indian and then you might.

Comment: @user5577  You have to interpret "now" in context.  "She is writing a book" means that she is in the middle of writing a book, even if she isn't writing the book at this very moment.  But you aren't in the process of checking mail, it is just something you do regularly.

Comment: "I am reading the book" means you are in the process of reading it, but not necessarily reading at this moment; just as "I am working as a shop assistant" doesn't necessarily mean you are working right now, and "I am learning Spanish" means you are enrolled in a Spanish class or doing other study on a regular basis. In all cases, you started doing something and you will go back to it: it is an ongoing process.

Comment: @StuartF Ok, I understand the distinction you all are making now. I've edited my post to clarify. A process that is going on now at least as a work in progress.